# Gparted: Copy Greyed Out

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, lvm

I booted my system to a gparted linux live CD and I have two partitions:

/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2

I want to move both of them to my new physical hard drive (called /dev/sdb). When I right click on /dev/sda1, I can choose copy and then paste it onto /dev/sdb. When I right click on /dev/sda2, copy is greyed out and there is a yellow exclamation point to the left of the disk. I know that the disk works since I can boot my computer from it.

Why won't gparted let me copy /dev/sda2 to my new hard disk? Since the option is greyed out, I don't even get an error message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

GParted does not support lvm2 file systems. See bug 160787:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160787